# How to choose module's flavour in Android Studio with 3.x.x Gradle plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I have project with this configuration:

```
App > ModuleA
```

ModuleA has two flavors: free and paid

App has

```
  missingDimensionStrategy 'type', 'free'
```

to set default flavors.

But now in AS 3.2.1 (Gradle plugin 3.2.1) with new variant-aware system I can't choose build variant only for moduleA without changing App.
I have only two possibilities:

1. Update missingDimensionStrategy to set another default value
2. Add additional flavors to App which will be correspondent with flavors in ModuleA

Is there any possibility to do it without changing Gradle script?

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you an example for you

moduleA's build.gradle file as follow:

```
...
productFlavors {
    ...
    free{
      ...
    }
    paied{
       ...
    }
    ...
} 
...
```

Then you can add same productFlavors for you app's build.gradle file,

```
...
productFlavors {
    ...
    free{
      ...
    }
    paied{
       ...
    }
    ...
} 
...
```

after setting then you can choose it in AS for moduleA and app, it will work fine.

Comment: Yes, I know, it's my workaround #2 in my question. What's about this case:
App > ModuleA > ModuleB > ModuleC
You will need to add flavors in each module from C to App to make it work.